# std::map insert() hint location: difference between c++98 and c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, insert

On [cplusplus' entry on map::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) I read about the location one could add as a hint for the function that the "function optimizes its insertion time if `position` points to the element that will **precede** the inserted element" for c++98, while for c++11 the optimization occurs "if `position` points to the element that will **follow** the inserted element (or to the end, if it would be the last)".

Does this mean that the performance of code snippets of the following form (which are abundant in the legacy code I'm working on and modeled after [Scott Meyer](http://www.aristeia.com/)'s "Effective STL", item 24) were affected in switching to a C++11-compliant compiler?

```
auto pLoc = someMap.lower_bound(someKey);
if(pLoc != someMap.end() && !(someMap.key_comp()(someKey, pLoc->first)))
    return pLoc->second;
else
    auto newValue = expensiveCalculation();
    someMap.insert(pLoc, make_pair(someKey, newValue));  // using the lower bound as hint
    return newValue;
```

What would be the best way to improve this pattern for use with C++11?

Comment: See [LWG issue 233](http://wg21.link/lwg233) and [N1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html). I'm not sure if whether there exists any implementation that actually implements the C++98 spec.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So would you prefer bug for bug compatibility with C++98, just like Wine promises for the Windows API? At one time there was another serious security bug in Windows, and the same vulnerability was found in Wine, which is of course a totally different implementation of the same API spec. It's sort of impressive, but I would rather that ISO fixes the defects from C++98 instead of propagating them to eternity.

Comment: @ArneVogel: I'm with you to a degree, but the manner in which this particular change snuck in does not seem acceptable. Not only does it silently ruin earlier programs, but it's also a really subtle change that I doubt many people would even notice. It just seems largely contrary to the C++ project's stated goals, which is a trend on the rise. Don't get me wrong, though: I don't have a better suggestion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are there actual "earlier programs" written against the C++98 spec? Because that would require using, say, `lower_bound` and then decrementing the returned iterator - after checking that it isn't `begin()` because it would be UB otherwise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C++98 specification is a defect in the standard. See the discussion in [LWG issue 233](http://wg21.link/lwg233) and [N1780](http://wg21.link/n1780).

Recall that `lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element with key not less than the specified key, while `upper_bound` returns an iterator to the first element with key greater than the specified key. If there is no key equivalent to the specified key in the container, then `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` return the same thing - an iterator to the element that would be *after* the key if it were in the map.

So, in other words, your current code already works correctly under the C++11 spec, and in fact would be wrong under C++98's defective specification.

Comment: Great answer! I just want to add that the old spec did not allow providing a hint when the new key was known to be less than any existing key (i.e. inserting at the front) while `end()` was not useful for anything. With the fix, the hint iterator works the same as the iterator passed to a sequence container's `insert()`, which resolves this issue.

Comment: @ArneVogel Yep, that's mentioned at the beginning of N1780.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will affect the complexity. Giving the correct hint will make `insert()` have amortized constant complexity, while giving and incorrect hint will force the map to search for the position from the beginning, giving logarithmic complexity. Basically, a good hint makes the insertion happen in constant time, no matter how big your map is; with a bad hint the insertion will be slower on larger maps.

The solution is, apparently, to search for the hint with `upper_bound` instead of `lower_bound`.

Answer (score -2):

I am thinking the correct C++11-style hint insertion might be as follows:

```
iterator it = table.upper_bound(key);   //upper_bound returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key
if (it == table.begin() || (--it)->first < key) {
    // key not found path
    table.insert(it, make_pair(key, value));
}
else {
    // key found path
    it->second = value;
}
```

Comment: This will crash if `table` is empty.

Answer (score -2):

A snapshot of working lambda function for your reference.
Note: `m_map` should not be empty. It is trivially known where to add the element if the map is empty.

```
    auto create_or_get_iter = [this] (const K& key) {

        auto it_upper = m_map.upper_bound(key);
        auto it_effective = it_upper == m_map.begin() ? it_upper : std::prev(it_upper);
        auto init_val = it_effective->second;

        if (it_effective == m_map.begin() || it_effective->first < key) {
            return m_map.insert(it_effective, std::make_pair(key, init_val));
        } else {
            it_effective->second = init_val;
            return it_effective;
        }

    };
```