# Fast Insertions into STL map

Tags: c++, stl

The following code is from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/). It has two inserts labelled as efficient and inefficient. I think that the efficient one should give the hint to be `mymap.begin() + 1`, because `*(mymap.begin() + 1)` is `'z'` and `z` will follow `b`.

> The function optimizes its insertion time if position points to the
>   element that will follow the inserted element (or to the end, if it
>   would be the last).

The best hint for inserting `'c'` would be `*(mymap.begin() + 2)`, because it has to pass `'a'` and `'b'`.
Right or wrong? I tried timing my proposed code and comparing it to the 'efficient' one here, but I see no difference. Probably because I have a million tabs open and music playing too, and because this is a trivial example.

```
  std::map<char,int> mymap;

  // first insert function version (single parameter):
  mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',100) );
  mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',200) );

  // second insert function version (with hint position):
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('b',300));  // max efficiency inserting
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('c',400));  // no max efficiency inserting
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just say: `mymap['c'] = 400;` ?

Comment: i probably would but im just reading the docs to refresh my memory when i came across this tidbit.

Comment: it is `begin()+1`. You want to point to the second element (the element preceding the future position of the inserted element)

Comment: How did you do the timing?

Comment: I just used ctime and CLOCKS_PER_SEC and had a for loop that looped N times over the code you see above with the max efficiency inserting. Then another for loop for N iterations were it starts as begin() + 1.

Comment: This example is so small that you're very unlikely to see any measurable difference between amortized constant and logarithmic time. Try a map with a few million entries and many insertions.

Comment: By the way: you're referring to C++11 documentation, but the example is C++98. (Compare the C++11 and C++98 documentations for `position`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of the semantics of hinted inserts changed with C++11 (as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759125/1566221)). See [DR 233](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#233) for the resolution and [N1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html) for part of the discussion which lead to that resolution.

The defect report and discussion paper are primarily about `std::multimap` and `std::multiset`, in which duplicate keys are allowed. In that case, if the "hint" refers to an element with a key equal to the key being inserted, then the new element could be inserted either before or after the hint and the pre-C++11 standard left that ambiguous. DR233 makes the decision deterministic, but it also can be read as affecting the specification of behaviour for `std::map` and `std::set`.

In the original specification (prior to C+11), the standard simply said "iterator `p` is a hint pointing to where the insert should start to search," which is not very specific about whether the hint should point before or after the insertion point. (Nor does it says anything about how the search proceeds in case the hint is wrong, since the new element must be inserted at a correct position regardless of the hint.) However, the complexity of the operation was documented as being "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if `t` is inserted right after `p`".

That complexity specification is obviously wrong on two counts: first, it does not insist on constant time insertion if `t` is *not inserted* (because the hint points to an element whose key compares equal), but any reasonable implementation could hardly fail to be constant-time in this case. Second, if the new element is to be inserted at the beginning of the container, there is no possible way of specifying a hint prior to the insertion point.

In fact, major implementations of the standard library actually expected the hint to point just after the insertion point, although most also checked to see if it was just before. So existing practice was to provide amortized constant time complexity in cases not required by the standard (which, of course, is permitted), with at least one widely-used implementation failing to provide the required complexity.

So the code in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) is, at best, imprecise, and definitely fails to describe a normal use case for hinted insertion.

Suppose that it is expensive to construct a mapped value for a given key. (Perhaps the map memoizes an expensive function and there is no cheap default constructor for the mapped value.) In that case, you probably would want to check to see if the map already contains the key before going to the trouble to compute the corresponding value which would need to be inserted. A naive implementation would be something like:

```
if (mymap.find(key) == mymap.end())
   mymap[key] = expensive_function(key);
// See Note 1 for another slightly more efficient variant
```

The result is that the same logarithmic search is done twice if the key is not present. Of course, the extra cost of the unnecessary search is probably trivial compared with the cost of `expensive_function`, but, still, it seems like there would be a better solution. Which there is: we do the first search with [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound), leading to the only slightly more complex code:

```
auto where = mymap.lower_bound(key);
if (where == mymap.end() || where->first != key) 
  where = mymap.emplace_hint(where, key, expensive_function(key));
/* Here, 'where' points to the element with the specified key */
```

(I used [`std::map::emplace_hint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) -- available since C++11 -- rather than `insert` in part to attempt to avoid an unnecessary copy, as well as to avoid cluttering the code with `std::make_pair`.)

#### Notes

1. Instances of that code are very easy to find. Many go on to reference `mymap[key]` in order to use the stored value, adding yet another unnecessary logarithmic search; better code would be:

   ```
   auto where = mymap.find(key);
   if (where == mymap.end())
     where = mymap.emplace(key, expensive_function(key)).first;
   ```

Comment: Who would have thought someone would have asked the same question already. I think mine could be marked as a duplicate because the one you linked is about the same topic.

Comment: The hint given to `emplace_hint()` is an "iterator to the position before which the new element will be inserted", but `lower_bound()` returns "an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than key"; i.e., assuming that the key doesn't exist, `lower_bound()` will return an iterator to the element _just after_ where the key should be inserted. Unless I'm confused, surely the hint should be `std::prev(map.lower_bound(key))`?

Comment: @sirco: the "position before which the new element will be inserted" is the position just after where  the element would be inserted. The English phrasing "before which" might be confusing.

Comment: Exceedingly confusing, perhaps even to the point of being outright misleading. Many thanks for clarifying. For reference, the quotes in all their beautiful obscurity were taken from cppreference.com.

Answer (score 0):

The "efficient" version is only efficient if you provide it a good hint. Your hint (`.begin`) is wrong. Now, in a container with just two elements, you can't be *very* wrong, so the damage is limited.

Comment: In all the implementations I know of, it doesn't help to provide a hint which is close to the correct position. If the hint is even a little bit wrong, it is ignored. But you're obviously correct to say that there cannot be much damage from forcing a full lookup in a two-element map.